# Keep jQuery slidedown from pushing page down WITHOUT absolute positioning

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a simple jquery slidedown menu, but it's pushing the page down, and I don't really want that. I can't use absolute positioning.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMwtX/) of what I have right now.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you do relative-positioning with z-index? I don't see any other way for you to get the ul to render on top of the rest of the body. And then you'll need spacing above the body or it will appear underneath the unexpanded UL.

Comment: Why cant you use absolute positioning?

Comment: @n8wrl I am using absolute positioning with a z-index. I want the body to appear underneath the expanded url, similar to a dropdown menu.

Comment: @n8wrl *relative (trying to avoid absolute, sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the navbar in a container with fixed height. This prevents the content from moving.

```
<div class="navbar_container">
    <ul class="navbar">    
...
    </ul>
</div>

.navbar_container {
    height: 60px;
}
```

[Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z48JN/)

If you want the menu to go over the content you'll have to use absolute positioning though.

Comment: so there is no way around using absolute positioning? Technically this works...but it basically pushes the whole page down by default, the only difference is that the user doesn't see it...

Comment: If you don't use absolute positioning then your menu will always be inside the flow of the document and cause everything else to move around it.

Comment: okay. I guess if there's no workaround, I'll just minimize my margins and do my best to make it look like nothings happening to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use a containing div:

```
<div class="navbarWrapper">   
    <ul class="navbar">    
        <li class="link">Username
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="#">Profile</a><br />
                <a href="#">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

... and add to your CSS:

```
.navbarWrapper 
{
     height: 1em;
}

.navbar 
{
    ...   
    position: absolute;
    ...
}
```

Comment: he specified without aboslute positioning.